# PHPMailer can not send email now

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Anyone have any project send email from `localhost` using `PHPMailer` for send email ?

I have 2 project using it and now it's stop send email both, it's show message `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.` the same, I think `PHPMailer` have problem now ?

Any one meeting problem like me or it's just my imagine ?

Comment: check whether there's an mta running on the "localhost" like sendmail or postfix. If not, the above message will occur.

Comment: What output occurs, when you run this command on a shell "mail -s “My test mail” mail@domain.com"?

Comment: My code send mail as well, just a few day it's stop

Answer (score 1):

The way you have this setup, it would require an SMTP server running on the localhost to send the messages through. If you don't have an SMTP server running on this localhost, then you can use an external SMTP server to relay the messages through.

Here is a working example:

[Having trouble with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344239/having-trouble-with-phpmailer)

Comment: Yes my code is like this too, before it's send email as well, just a few day it's stop send

Comment: @Time Can you enable debug and tell us the messages your receiving: `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1`

Comment: yes after i `$mail->SMTPDebug =1` it's show message `SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (0) SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host`

Comment: @Time have you tried configuring your SMTP to listen to Port 587 or 25

Comment: port 587 , SMTPSecure tls

Comment: Try following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321030/phpmailercan-not-send-email

Comment: is mine, it's my question! I try it already but no result yet