# PHPMailer SMTP connect() failed on CONTABO VPS but worked locally

Tags: php, apache, phpmailer, vps

This code works very fine locally. But when I put it Online on my VPS it does not work. Can someone please explain me why?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

//Encoding da base de dados
$mail->Encoding = "base64";

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = 'login';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'something.domain.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'myusername@domain.com';
$mail->Password = '*mypass*';

$mail->SetFrom('somename@domain.com', 'Myname');
$mail->Subject = 'Email de teste';
$mail->Body = 'The content';
$mail->AddAddress('destination@server.com');
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: If it's already working locally, some Hosting companies block outgoing email ports, for security. You might need to request support to get it open. You should enable your debugging to see what's the error you're getting on the VPS. To test if it's blocked, just `telnet something.domain.com 465` if you can't connect it's blocked. If you can, the problem is something else.

Comment: "It does not work" is no use in diagnosing your problem. You could try [this community wiki answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321030/phpmailercan-not-send-email/25322783#25322783), which covers this.