# PHP Mailer Shows Error : Mailer Error smtp connect failed. How to fix?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Hi I am using PHP mailer 6.1.6 to send emails using a gmail account. This is my code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    //Server settings                     // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'me@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';                               // SMTP password
    
    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS; 
    
    
    // $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         
    // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port = 465;
```

// TCP port to connect to
//use 465 for

```
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('me@gmail.com','Me');
    $mail->addAddress($eemail);
```

It shows the following error.

Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Please suggest a fix for gmail, yahoo mail or any other service. Thanking in anticipation

Comment: _"Please suggest a fix"_ Maybe click that link?

Comment: And perhaps [search before you post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+SMTP+connect%28%29+failed)?

Comment: guys I did search and I did ask it on Git. ;)

Comment: Try enabling less secure apps in your gmail account [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4P6AfPXgmIN1ZgXpNqLVn4-O5eQ-qlmhubhd71TKMLRQMfJ2l5SzPpn7rsz9tP9LJTDLJEtqt0dMSGZTClMqIHff3kPaA).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPMailer, SMTP connect() failed error with Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924651/phpmailer-smtp-connect-failed-error-with-gmail)

Comment: Nope it did'nt work