# Called Mail() without being connected while sending email using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail using phpmailer but it is giving error

```
<?php
   include("/mail/class.phpmailer.php");

    // Basic Header Input
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = 'username'; // your GMail user name
    $mail->Password = 'password';           //"Password";
    // ---------- adjust these lines ---------------------------------------

    $mail->From= 'mg@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName="My site's mailer";
    $mail->AddAddress("mg123@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = "Your invoice";

    $mail->IsHTML(false);
    $mail->AddAttachment('test1.pdf', 'invoice.pdf'); // attach files/invoice-user-1234.pdf, and rename it to invoice.pdf
    $mail->Body = "Please find your invoice attached.";
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Letter is sent";
    }
```

?>

it is showing error like Error sending:

> "Error sending: The following From address failed:
>   mg@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected"

i try with adding code $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; then it is showing error like below

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
>   (0)  The following From address failed: mg@gmail.com
>   : Called Mail() without being connected

Comment: use this $mail->From= "mg@gmail.com";

Comment: single quote is not completed

Comment: Tell me now is this working?

Comment: and also $mail->FromName="My site\'s mailer";

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its not working.

Comment: It might sound like a radical idea, but you could try looking at [the example gmail code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) provided by PHPMailer. Don't use SSL/465 on gmail; Use TLS on port 487. And update your PHPMailer.

Comment: i try with adding code $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; then it is givving me error like below
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0) 
The following From address failed: manisha.gaidhane8788@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

Comment: That sounds like your DNS isn't working. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321030/phpmailer-cannot-send-email/25322783#25322783).

Comment: Chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909348/how-to-send-email-with-smtp-in-php/25911209#25911209

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
$mail->From= 'mg@gmail.com';
```

You are mixing single quotes and double quotes

Comment: Thanks for reply i have tried with this also but same error is there

Comment: @MGaidhane heck class.phpmailer.php is connected properly ?

Comment: i checked it and it is working properly. i am getting error like..... "SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)"