# Phpmhailer having an error on 000webhost I cant send or receive email in live server

Tags: phpmailer, web-hosting

**Hello guys can anyone help me on how to solve this problem .. I really don't know how to solved this because its my first time to upload a project for hosting. So I have this**
[Registration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24j89.png)** and when its completely filled up it will send a message to the student email. and to implement that I use PHPmailer and use my google account as host. This work perfectly fine on my local server but when I upload this on (000webhost.com) a free hosting site Im getting an [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCIq3.png)** this is my code for phpMhailer

```
$fname = $_POST['first'];

$mname = $_POST['middle'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$name = $fname;
$emails = $email;
$mes ='';
                                                                                            
                                                                                                            
//  "Your email is $email";                                                                                                           
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
                                                                                                            
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP                                                                                            
                                                                                                   
$mail->SMTPDebug = true; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
                                                                                                            
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
                                                                                                            
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // ssl/tls secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
                                                                                                            
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                                                                                                            
$mail->Port = 465; // 465 or 587
                                                                                                            
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
                                                                                                        
$mail->Username = "mygmailaccount@gmail.com";
                                                                                                            
$mail->Password = "mygmailpassword";
                                                                                                            
$mail->SetFrom("mygmailaccount@gmail.com");
                                                                                                            
$mail->Subject = "JPIMSS"; 
                                                                                                                              
// $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("../img/email`ogo.png", "logo");
                                                                                                            
$mail->Body ="<div style='display:flex; font-size:20px;  align-items: center; color:green;'> 
<span>John Paul Integrated Montessori School of Silang</span></div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
<div>
                                                                                                            
<p style= 'font-size:18px'> Hello! $fname
                                                                                                            
<br>                                                                                                         
-------------------------                                                                                                          
<br>                                                                                                      
Username: $emails                                                                                                        
<br>                                                                                                 
Password: $pass                                                                                                            
<br> 
------------------------                                                                                                            
</p>                                                                                                              
<br
                                                                                                            
<p style= 'font-size:18px'></p>
                                                                                                            
</div>";
                                                                                                            
$mail->AddAddress($emails);
                                                                                            
                                                                                                            
if(!$mail->Send()) {
                                                                                                                
$msg = "Mailer Error:".$mail->ErrorInfo;
                                                                                                                
$msg = "Fail";
                                                                                                            
} else {
                                                                                                                 
$_POST = array();
                                                                                                                
$msg = "<div class='col-md-12 alert alert-success fade show alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
                                                                                                                
<i class='fa fa-check-circle' aria-hidden='true' style='color:green'></i> Submitted please 
check your email for your <b>username</b> and <b>password</b>  
                                                                                                                
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
                                                                                                                  
<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                                                                                                                
</button>
                                                                                                              
</div>";                                                                                                            
}
```

**Note: This code is perfectly fine on my local server using xampp I can receive and send email using this code. Thank you in advance I really appreciate your help :) **

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321030/phpmailer-cannot-send-email

Comment: `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` will not work with `Port = 465`. Change `SMTPSecure` to `ssl`. You are setting `$msg` twice and not echoing it at all, so you'll never see what is in it.

Comment: I did get a $msg . and this the error I get..   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YqZL3Lx9r7jb-nk0-PSIgJyWdIvLqjJk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Synchro I change now SMTPSecure = 'tls' to 'ssl' and its work .Thank you sir for your reply i appreciated it